# Converting multiple string columns to enum in H2o Flow

Tags: python, pyspark, h2o

I'm having more than 100 String Columns which I need to be converting into enum so that the ML model identifies theses columns as categories.

In Pyspark, there is no Category type (as in Pandas) and hence I casted all categories as 'String'. I don't want to click 'convert to enum' > 100 times and I'm sure there is an easier way to perform this task. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find a coding solution. But found an easier way - saved the pyspark df as a parquet in hdfs and imported it into h2o. All string columns were auto-recognised as Enum.